# How to get an Azure Webjob to process multiple queue messages?

Tags: azure, queue, message, azure-webjobssdk, batching

In Azure worker roles, you can create a batch job that processes a list of messages. I'm wondering if there is something similar to that for Azure WebJobs?

Currently you can trigger a webjob from a queue as follows:

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, TextWriter log)
```

Is there some way to pull and process a list of messages?

Comment: There's a backlogged feature request. Chime in if you'd like to see it. https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/625

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no inbuilt binding for a batch of Queue messages currently.

However, someone in the community has recently created such a binding using the WebJobs SDK extensibility model. I have not used that binding yet, but you might give it a try and provide feedback to the author. See the **GroupQueueTrigger** [repo](https://github.com/ealsur/WebJobs.Extensions.GroupQueueTrigger) and more information. It allows you to bind to a `List<T>` of messages.

Comment: Seems like a possible, but not a perfect solution.

The GroupQueueTrigger implementation in that repo seems to use a random backoff, instead of the standard exponential one, only supports a max batch size of 32 (a single storage call), and only returns a success true/false, so there isn't a way to tell if everything in the batch failed, or just one thing failed. 

I'll try and modify it to suit my needs. Thanks again Mathew!

Comment: In regards to max batch size - you can't get more than 32 messages per call. This is a Storage service limit. Have you had any progress on the other items?