# Making a list of Func or Action as AzureFunction with trigger

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm in the need of doing dynamic number of AzureFunctions that need to be activated by `[ServiceBusTrigger(functionObject.Name, Connection = "")]` so I willl have something like this:

```
public class FunctionObject(){
public string Name {get; set;}
public Action<string, Ilogger> Function {get; set; }
}

List<FunctionObject>
```

And I want to generate an Azure funtion for every element of the List

Is this possible right now?

Comment: Why would you need that ?

Comment: Why do you want to create separate azure function for every element in your list, You could utilize auto scaling of the instances and you can try to implement action in  the same function only. If this doesn't suffice and you know all the Action item then you can define an Azure function for every single Action item and send a trigger when there is an entry in myqueue.

Comment: I need the queue name to be diferent for every item on the list I'm going to update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something which you can do , as per the ideal scenario:

- Create multiple function if you are certain and know the number of queue/action item in your case.
- When there is any message in the queue, try to add the message in other queue as per your need.
- Once the other function service bus trigger would run and they get the message automatically , your function will be executed.

Though listening ti multiple queue is possible as you create a custom trigger to read the messages from them.

Please check this post for the design idea which you can perform in Azure web job:

[How to get an Azure Webjob to process multiple queue messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001148/how-to-get-an-azure-webjob-to-process-multiple-queue-messages)

Also check the below post as well :

[one listener for multiple azure queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46964689/one-listener-for-multiple-azure-queues/47005363)

Hope it helps.